# What's the meaning of `pronounced bye-frost`?

Tags: meaning, phrases

When I read the [document](https://docs.openstack.org/bifrost/latest/):

> Bifrost (pronounced bye-frost) is a set of Ansible playbooks that automates the task of deploying a base image onto a set of known hardware using ironic.

What's the meaning of `pronounced bye-frost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way you should pronounce the word (say the word) In this case they are telling you that the second letter sound is EYE.

Comment: thank you, I understand now.